# How to send keystrokes

Tags: macos, delphi, clipboard, sendkeys, delphi-xe7

I'm converting a previous application to Delphi XE7 firemonkey, to add support for OSX. The application has to be able to copy text selected in the previous "In front" application, when a button is pressed.

Ie: User have browser open, select some text on the page, then click a button in my application and the text is copied to my application.

I did this in a Windows only application by using sendkey32.pas, sending first ALT+TAB and then CTRL+C, then I could get the text from clipboard.

I have searched for solution doing the same in firemonkey project, but can't find any ideas on how to do it.

Comment: You mean you want to do this for OSX? You already know how to do it for windows right?

Comment: Yes, I need to know how to do this in firemonkey project for OSX

Comment: Keys for OSX is "CMD+TAB" and "CMD+C" but don't know how to send the keystrokes from my application.